# synchronisation issue within callback functions

Tags: c, linux

In a continuous loop barcodes are scanned and if scan is valid text data and voice data are read out/played, which happens in differnt context. Text playback happens first, then its callback function gets executed, from there voice playback happens, and then its callback function. The issue is seen when multiple scanning is done, sometimes there is synchronisation issues. While text playback of 1st barcode is happening, if another scan is done, then voice data of 2nd barcode gets played(skipping text playback of 2nd). This behaviour is observed only sometimes, so it is kind of difficult to debug.

Any ideas how to provide synchronisation within callbacks?

Thanks in advance for any help.

-Aparna

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't very clear so lets assume you currently have 3 threads

1. Reads the barcode from hardware
2. Displays the code?
3. Audio playback of the code as text contained in the barcode

The thread reading the barcode is a producer of data and should push a work unit onto a consumer stack and should notify the stack that there is a work unit.  Run a cursory google search for producer-consumer queue.

Threads 2 & 3 appear to be synchronous and should be combined into a single thread?

Comment: Let me try to put in more clarity.                             Thread 1: reads barcode, if its a valid barcode read out text data from a file and give it to tts engine for text read out. After tts engine has completed, another callback function, ttscallback() gets called, which is in same context as thread1. [ttscallback and thread1 are defined in same file] From the ttscallback, if the barcode has some audio files associated with it, that gets played next, and after completion the audiocallback() func gets executed. [audiocallback also in same file]